# Something in this function is crashing my program!

Tags: c++, crash, switch-statement

Howdy, When my program begins executing the code in case N of the switch statement it crashes. I am not sure why. Anyone care to take a gander?

**Code:** (I suspect the problem is occurring somewhere in case N of the switch statement)

```
#include "header.h"

void findSeats(int& FC_Row, int& FC_Col, int& EconRow, int& EconCol, int& ticketNum, int& rowNum, char& ticketType, char& seatType, int airplane[][6])
{
    int aisle,  col;
    char letterCol;

    if (ticketType = 'F')
        {
            switch (seatType)
            {
                case 'W':
                if (airplane[rowNum - 1][0] == 0)
                    {
                    airplane[rowNum - 1][0] = 1;
                    cout << "Your seat is " << (rowNum) <<  "A" << endl;
                    }
                else if (airplane[rowNum-1][FC_Col - 1] == 0)
                    {
                    airplane[rowNum - 1][FC_Col] = 1;
                    cout << "Your seat is " << (rowNum) <<  "D" << endl;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    cout << "There are no window seats in that row. Please choose a different row." << '\n' << "(use the seating chart to determin where open seats are.)" << '\n' << "Row Number:" <<  endl;
                    cin >> rowNum;
                    while (rowNum > (FC_Row))
                    {
                        cout << "That row is not located in our first class section. choose a row numbered 1-" << (FC_Row) << endl;
                        cin >> rowNum;
                    }
                    findSeats(FC_Row, FC_Col, EconRow, EconCol, ticketNum, rowNum, ticketType, seatType, airplane);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'A':
                aisle = (FC_Col / 2);
                if (airplane[rowNum - 1][aisle - 1] == 0)
                    {
                    airplane[rowNum - 1][aisle - 1] = 1;
                    cout << "Your seat is " << (rowNum) <<  "B" << endl;
                    }
                else if (airplane[rowNum-1][aisle] == 0)
                    {
                    airplane[rowNum - 1][aisle] = 1;
                    cout << "Your seat is " << (rowNum) <<  "C" << endl;
                    }
                else
                    {
                    cout << "There are no aisle seats in that row. Please choose a different row." << '\n' << "(use the seating chart to determin where open seats are.)" << '\n' << "Row Number:" <<  endl;
                    cin >> rowNum;
                    while (rowNum > (FC_Row))
                    {
                        cout << "That row is not located in our first class section. choose a row numbered 1-" << (FC_Row) << endl;
                        cin >> rowNum;
                    }
                    findSeats(FC_Row, FC_Col, EconRow, EconCol, ticketNum, rowNum, ticketType, seatType, airplane);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'N':
                col = 0;
                while (airplane[rowNum - 1][col] == 1)
                    {
                    for (col; airplane[rowNum - 1][col]; col++)
                        {
                        if (col > 3)
                            {
                                cout << "There are no available seats in that row. Please choose a different row." << '\n' << "(use the seating chart to determin where open seats are.)" << '\n' << "Row Number:" <<  endl;
                                cin >> rowNum;
                            }
                            while (rowNum > (FC_Row))
                            {
                                cout << "That row is not located in our first class section. choose a row numbered 1-" << (FC_Row) << endl;
                                cin >> rowNum;
                            }
                            ticketType, seatType, airplane);
                        }
                    }
                    airplane[rowNum - 1][col] = 1;
                    switch (col)
                    {
                        case 0:
                        letterCol = 'A';
                        break;
                        case 1:
                        letterCol = 'B';
                        break;
                        case 2:
                        letterCol = 'C';
                        break;
                        case 3:
                        letterCol = 'D';
                        break;
                    }
                    cout << "Your seat is " << (rowNum) <<  "letterCol" << endl;


            }
        }
}
```

removing the function call to itself solved the issue.

Comment: If _you're_ guessing, then even reading your mind from a distance wont help _us_ much :-) Please run your code in a debugger to pinpoint where it is breaking, and update your question with that information.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the crash, but I'm quite sure that you want to replace `ticketType = 'F'` (which _assigns_ `'F'` to `ticketType`) by `ticketType == 'F'` (which _compares_ the values).

Comment: Its not really a guess, the program gets to that case in the switch statement and then crashes lol

Comment: Also: You should execute the program with `gdb` (or with your IDE's debugger) and give us the stack trace, which _might_ make it possible for us non-mind readers to figure out why it's crashing.

Comment: @Aasamund, Im not familiar with this what a debugger does. I am using code blocks and usually just hit the build and run button to test my program. Please forgive me for my ignorance.

Comment: @Aasamund, I can debug in code blocks by pressing f8. This seems like the program runs (consol application) till I get to the spot where it crashes then a window that says call stack in the corner pops up. Not sure what this is

Comment: @Matt: Good. The call stack tells which functions have called which functions, and at which line your program crashed. Which line is it? When the program crashes during debugging, I assume that CodeBlocks "pauses" the program and lets you inspect the values of the variables (try hovering the mouse over different variables). What are the values of the variables at the line where it crashes?

Comment: Hmm, there is a yellow arrow point to line 77, where i recall the findseats function

Comment: You're working in C++ and barely taking advantage of it. I would consider wrapping some of these values in to classes and managing this in a more object oriented way. You may find this eases debugging and also makes it easier to add features later (for extra credit, later parts of the assignment, or just for your own learning and curiousity.)

Comment: @Matt: Strange; I can't see why it should crash at that function call, except if it is a stack overflow. How big is the call stack? Is it a couple of lines long, or thousands of lines? I didn't see before now that `findSeats` is recursive (it calls itself) - is that intentional?

Comment: for (col; airplane[rowNum - 1][col]; col++) isn't this an infinite loop? wouldn't this segfault sooner or later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `rownum` is `0`

Negative indexes are bad.

Comment: rowNum is input by the user and the true row number in the array is one less thats the reason for the subtraction. Furthur, rowNum is checked to be greater than 0 during its input.

Comment: Guess #2 would be that you're blowing out the stack by calling `findseats()` recursively from there without making any changes to the parameters. That's all I got. Without the rest of the code or a stack trace, we're all just guessing.